# how to install Tensonflow on a Mac

Tags: macos, tensorflow, deep-learning, installation

This time I try to use a **Tensorflow** using a **Mac**, and I write to know how to install **Tensorflow**.

I want to know about 4 things to note when installing.

1. Anaconda
2. Keras
3. Tensorflow
4. Pycharm

   - interpreter, path
5. Library

I really want to know **install** **path**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, install anaconda in your system then run the following command to install Tensorflow.

```
pip install tensorflow
```